# shortening a globe light string

Tags: lighting

Shortening a globe light string.
I have a 100 foot G40, E12 base, C7 socket globe light string.
I want to shorten it by 6 feet. I have very little electrical experience.
How can I easily do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with electronics engineering. Maybe a better fit for DIY?

Comment: We're just supposed to know that a "globle light string" and a "100 foot G40" are?  No definitions, no references, *screw this*.

Comment: Is this line voltage (110/120V plug-in style) or low voltage (12/24VDC hard-wired)? Also, what wattage are the lamps and what is the spacing between each lamp? Likely you can just cut the line at the desired length and cap it, but I'd be interested to know exactly what you have beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming yours is something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00L1FIN4I) then the bulbs are in parallel, so all you have to do is cut it and isolate/cap the wire ends; *do not* connect/short these wire ends together.

Oh, and make sure it's de-energized/unplugged when you cut it.

Comment: Agreed, and I think that "C7" is the most important part.  C7 and C9 lights are 120v, so you can cut the parallel string anywhere.